# If admin theme is 'seven' disable the module

Tags: 8, hooks

So in a custom module, I'd like to check whether the theme is seven or not, if it's seven the module shouldn't load/work.

Note: I have a module that shouldn't override half of UI of seven theme but should work if it's any other theme, played around with theme.manager for now but still struggling.

Comment: What for? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a module that shouldn't override half of UI of `seven` theme but should work if it's any other theme, played around with `theme.manager` for now but still struggling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom EventSusbcriber ( [read this](https://x-team.com/blog/creating-and-subscribing-to-events/) for more information )

then check if the current theme is `seven` with and `MODULE_NAME` is enabled

```
  $moduleHandler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');
    if (\Drupal::service('theme.manager')->getActiveTheme()=='seven' && $moduleHandler->moduleExists('MODULE_NAME')){
```

then try to uninstall with

```
    $moduleHandler->uninstall(['MODULE_NAME']);
```

**Finally, The total solution should be something like**

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events['kernel.request'] = ['uninstallModuleIfThemeIsSeven'];

    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * This method is called whenever the kernel.request event is
   * dispatched.
   *
   * @param GetResponseEvent $event
   */
  public function uninstallModuleIfThemeIsSeven(GetResponseEvent $event) {
  $moduleHandler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');
    if (\Drupal::service('theme.manager')->getActiveTheme()=='seven' && $moduleHandler->moduleExists('MODULE_NAME')){
        $moduleHandler->uninstall(['MODULE_NAME']);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yusef, one thing to mention is that I'm not trying to uninstall the module but to disable it, I still want the module to work on another themes (front theme let's say)

Comment: @Sohail So it depends on the functionality you have in the module. would you please provide more details about the functionality you want to disable in your question and let me know after you update it?

Comment: @Sohail 

why you don't wrap your functionality on a condition I mean

       if (\Drupal::service('theme.manager')->getActiveTheme()!='seven'){
           // put your module functionality here
        }

Comment: Yep that's what I'm trying, I suppose I can unset the libraries loaded based on theme condition, Imma try now and let you know, thanks

Comment: Seems like I'm struggling a bit, there are some stylesheets I'm trying to unset if the active theme is `seven`

Comment: @Sohail I suggest you do it in another way. if the theme is not seven add it !!!